# Applescript to get the URL from Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, applescript

I'm trying to get the URL from Safari, close the tab and open it in Chrome ( [TUAW Post](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDIQFjAC&url=http://www.tuaw.com/2011/03/14/use-applescript-to-open-current-safari-url-in-google-chrome/&ei=GTdaTr7VMs7Gswaf3NmnCw&usg=AFQjCNE_4K1EqgCOC3tmUiiiRDMyhKPv-w&sig2=jPK1vMai1fZVrmX97nBYBw) ) But I keep getting the error:

```
error "Safari got an error: Can’t get current tab." number -1728 from current tab
```

From the code line:

```
set theURL to URL of current tab of window 1
```

Any suggestions?

All the code:

```
property theURL : ""

tell application "Safari"

    set t set theURL to URL of current tab of window 1
    close current tab

end tell

tell application "Google Chrome"

    set URL of active tab of window 1 to theURL

    activate

end tell
```

Comment: By any chance, was your Safari window full screen?

Comment: Don't remember. But the solution to my problem is posted further down the page

Comment: But the line of code that gave you trouble didn't change in the solution. I think this is a sporadic bug that happens only when Safari is full screen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works for me...

```
tell application "Safari"
    set theURL to URL of current tab of window 1
end tell
```

You have to show more code because the error is caused by something else. Let me ask you this, do you have the tell application Safari statement inside of another tell block? Maybe it's inside the tell google chrome block of code? If so remove it.

Comment: `property theURL : ""
tell application "Safari"
 
set theURL to URL of front document as string
 close current tab
 
end tell

tell application "Google Chrome"
 
 set URL of active tab of window 1 to theURL
 
 activate
 
end tell`

Comment: OK, now I see your error. It's in the "close" line. Make it this... close current tab of window 1.

Comment: Sry. That's not it. "error "Safari got an error: Can’t get URL of window 1." number -1728 from URL of window 1"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot guys! Here is the final code.

```
property theURL : ""

tell application "Safari"

    set theURL to URL of current tab of window 1

end tell

tell application "Google Chrome"

    tell window 1
        make new tab with properties {URL:theURL}
    end tell

    activate

end tell
```