# AppleScript for getting the frontmost url from Safari and open it in Google Chrome Incognito

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write an applescript that will get the current frontmost url from Safari and opens the same url in Google Chrome Incognito.

So far I know how to get the frontmost url from Safari, I am not sure how to open that url in Chrome incognito.

## MWE

```
tell application "Safari" to return URL of front document
tell application "Safari" to return name of front document
```

References:

- [Applescript to get the URL from Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221087/applescript-to-get-the-url-from-safari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes **Safari** is opened to a page with a **URL** and that **Google Chrome** exists on the system, however, if so, will do as you've requested.

**Note:** There is no *error handling* included to ensure **Safari** is opened to a page with a **URL** or whether or not **Google Chrome** exists on the system. That is for you to add.

```
tell application "Safari" to set theURL to the URL of the front document

do shell script "open -na 'Google Chrome' --args -incognito " & theURL's quoted form
```

The **Safari** line of *code* can also be written as:

```
tell application "Safari" to set theURL to the URL of the current tab of the front window
```

---

Here is an *example* with some *error handling* that uses **UI Scripting** and **System Events** instead of a `do shell script` *command* to open the *incognito window* in **Google Chrome**:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
if running of application "Safari" then
    
    tell application "Safari"
        if the URL of ¬
            the current tab of ¬
                the front window ¬
                    does not contain missing value then
            set theURL to ¬
                the URL of ¬
                    the current tab of ¬
                        the front window
        else
            return
        end if
    end tell
    
    tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
    
    delay 1
    
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        keystroke "n" using ¬
            {shift down, command down}
    
    delay 1
    
    tell application "Google Chrome" to ¬
        set the URL of ¬
            the active tab of ¬
                the front window to theURL
    
end if
```

---

### **Update to address comment:**

> ... is there a way if there is an incongito window already open, then open new url in a new tab?

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
if running of application "Safari" then
    
    tell application "Safari"
        if the URL of ¬
            the current tab of ¬
                the front window ¬
                    does not contain missing value then
            set theURL to ¬
                the URL of ¬
                    the current tab of ¬
                        the front window
        else
            return
        end if
    end tell
    
    if running of application "Google Chrome" then
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            if mode of front window is "incognito" then
                make new tab at end of ¬
                    front window with properties {URL:theURL}
            end if
        end tell
    end if

end if
```

---

### Update to address additional comments:

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* contains the necessary *error handling* to accommodate normal possible scenarios of the state of **Google Chrome** in regards to opening the **URL** of the current tab of the front window of **Safari** in an incognito window/tab of **Google Chrome**:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
if running of application "Safari" then
    
    tell application "Safari"
        if exists front window then
            if the URL of ¬
                the current tab of ¬
                    the front window ¬
                        does not contain missing value then
                set theURL to ¬
                    the URL of ¬
                        the current tab of ¬
                            the front window
            else
                return
            end if
        else
            return
        end if
    end tell
    
    if running of application "Google Chrome" then
        
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            set incognitoWindowIDs to ¬
                the id of every window ¬
                    whose mode is "incognito"
            if incognitoWindowIDs is {} then
                activate
                my openNewIncognitoWindow()
                delay 1
                set URL of ¬
                    the active tab of ¬
                        the front window to theURL
            else
                make new tab at end of ¬
                    window id (first item of incognitoWindowIDs) ¬
                        with properties {URL:theURL}
            end if
        end tell
    else
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            activate
            delay 1
            my openNewIncognitoWindow()
            delay 1
            set URL of ¬
                the active tab of ¬
                    the front window to theURL
        end tell
    end if
    
end if

on openNewIncognitoWindow()
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        keystroke "n" using ¬
            {shift down, command down}
end openNewIncognitoWindow
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: This is great. I have small problem, it opens new incog window each time, is there a way if there is an incongito window already open, then open new url in a new tab?

Comment: @MilkyWay001, RE: "is there a way if there is an incongito window already open, then open new url in a new tab?" --   Please see the  **Update to address comment:** section of the updated answer.

Comment: I coped the second code to and got this error: `$ osascript a.applescript 
a.applescript:558:569: execution error: Google Chrome got an error: Can’t get window 1. Invalid index. (-1719)`

Comment: Also, when normal google chrome is open, the code runs but does nothing. The code before update, works but it opens new chromes each time.

Comment: @MilkyWay001, I always test the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ I post before posting it,  and as written it works for me without issue from **Script Editor** or saving the _script_ and using `osascript` to execute it.

Comment: @MilkyWay001, Please understand that **Stack Overflow** is not a code writing service and I feel that what I've posted does indeed answer the OP and the first comment to my answer. Also as stated "_example_ **AppleScript** _code_", meaning if it does not suite every scenario you are trying to cover then you need to modify it accordingly to suit your needs.

Comment: @MilkyWay001, Please see the **Update to address additional comments:** section of the updated answer. It contains the necessary _error handling_ to accommodate normal possible scenarios of the state of **Google Chrome** in regards to opening the **URL** of the current tab of the front window of **Safari** in an incognito window/tab of **Google Chrome**.

Comment: @MilkyWay001, I forgot to add _error handling_ for if a _window_ wasn't open in **Safari**, so I've updated the _code_ in the **Update to address additional comments:** section of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using JavaScript, it's just few lines of code:

```
const chrome = Application('Google Chrome')
const safari_url = Application('Safari').documents[0].url()
chrome.Window({ mode: 'incognito' }).make()
chrome.windows[0].activeTab.url = safari_url
```